# Search by class name and text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am new to Selenium

I Can select by cssselector by class and text separately like below

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.md-tile-text--primary‌​.md-text")); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Getting Started')"));
```

How to combine both the above 2 statements into 1 line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.md-tile-text--primary‌​.md-text:contains('Getting Started')"));
```

Comment: Thanks Guy but somehow the code does not working in Java

Comment: @Savio What is the problem?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified getting this error @Guy

Comment: @Savio Are you sure `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:contains('Getting Started')"));` works for you? If not you can use `xpath` `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='md-tile-text--primary md-text'][contains(text(), 'Getting Started')]"));`